# Alternative for p:graphicImage which can show images from byte[] and control browser cache

Tags: jsf, primefaces, arrays, browser-cache, graphicimage

There seems to be a bug with `p:graphicimage` when using the update-functionality. Loading one image through `value="#{myController.myStreamedContent}"` works, but when changing `myController.myStreamedContent` followed by updating `p:graphicimage`, the previously loaded image remains unchanged. There is the possibilty to set `cache="false"`, but this does not work within my Firefox 45.0. I use PrimeFaces 5.3.

The following sites mention this, too:

- [PRIMEFACES - How to refresh a  from clicking a ?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20845992/primefaces-how-to-refresh-a-pgraphicimage-from-clicking-a-pcommandbutton)
- [Primefaces : GraphicImage does not refresh](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19305719/primefaces-graphicimage-does-not-refresh)
- [Why can't I update a p:graphicImage twice after upload a file with p:uploadFile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20082354/why-cant-i-update-a-pgraphicimage-twice-after-upload-a-file-with-puploadfile)

Are there any alternatives that provide similar or equal functionality to `p:graphicimage`? I basically need to be able to show images stored as `byte[]` within a `MEDIUMBLOB`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JSF utility library [OmniFaces](http://omnifaces.org) has a [`<o:graphicImage>`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/components/graphicImage) which does technically a better job in streaming and caching the images. It doesn't invoke the getter method [twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8207325/display-dynamic-image-from-database-with-pgraphicimage-and-streamedcontent), but only once when the browser really needs to download the image. Also, it supports consuming a `byte[]` or `InputStream` without the need for a wrapper. All in all, you end up with clearer model.

```
@Named
@ApplicationScoped
public class ImageStreamer {

    @Inject
    private ImageService service;

    public byte[] getById(Long id) {
        return service.getContent(id);
    }

}
```

```
<o:graphicImage value="#{imageStreamer.getById(bean.image.id)}" />
```

It by default forces the browser to not cache the image, so the image will be downloaded on every request. For efficiency, a `lastModified` attribute can be set to allow browsers to cache the image as long as the image is unchanged as per `lastModified` value.

```
<o:graphicImage value="#{imageStreamer.getById(bean.image.id)}" lastModified="#{bean.image.lastModified}" />
```